# Diagonalizing a matrix. Is it necessary to use $P^{-1}AP=D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

The matrix $D$ comes from $P^{-1}AP$, and has the form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
\gamma_1 & & \\
& \ddots & \\ 
& & \gamma_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

When asked to diagonalize, can I just put $\gamma$ values on the diagonal? The result will be different? There is a certain order for the eigenvalues on the diagonal?

I tought that maybe this formula was to prove that indeed the matrix is diagonalizable. If is just for that, there is any easier way to check? Inverting matrix often leads me to wrong calculations.

Comment: A simpler notation is $D = \text{diag}(\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there is a matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1}AP=D$, then you can use $D$ as the diagonal matrix.
The order of the $\gamma_i$ does not matter as long as the $i _{th}$ eigenvalue is associated to the $i_{th}$ eigenvector. If there is more than one eigenvector associated to an eigenvalue, I think you will need to use the Jordan form.

Comment: You need to use Jordan form when you can't make a basis of eigenvectors, that is, when the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces does not equal $n$, where the matrix's dimension is $n \times n$. What I think you're referring to here is you *may* (or may not) need to use Jordan form when the multiplicity of the eigenvalue (the exponent of the corresponding factor in the characteristic polynomial) is greater than $1$.

Comment: How do I know what $i{th}$ is the eigenvector or eigenvalue?

Comment: @JoãoPedro: I mean give the eigenvalues any numbering you choose, and once you have done that, the $-i- th$ vector has a well-defined name/numbering and it has an eigenvector(s) associated it to it.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Yes, I meant that when you have more than one eigenvector associated to a given eigenvalue, you may have to use Jordan Decomposition.

Comment: @Gary, While technically it is true in real vector spaces: there's always infinitely many eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvalue, there being more than one linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvalue has no bearing on whether you need to use generalised eigenvectors.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Yes, but I was referring to the case where the eigenspace associated to a fixed vector has dimension 2 or higher. Then I don't know which basis vector to choose when diagonalizing a matrix, as an eigenvector corresponding to a given eigenvalue.

Comment: @Gary, even in the case where one eigenspace has dimension $2$ or higher, you may not need generalised eigenvectors. For example, the (at least $2 \times 2$) identity matrix. Every vector is an eigenvector, and any basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a basis of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnonalize matrix A, you need to find its eigenvectors/eigenvalues. The matrix P is the matrix containing these eigenvectors ($P^{-1}$ is its inverse). The order of the eigenvectors also should correspond to the order of the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix D. Unfortunately, there's no easier way to do it and one important application of this process is in finding the values of matrices raised to very large powers-i.e. numerical optimization. It takes a bit of practise and once you get into it, it becomes easier.

e.g. Let's assume you need to calculate $A^{10}$, instead of multiplying A by itself 10 times, you can do the following:

$$ A^{10} = P( diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3 ))^{10}P^{-1}$$

$$ A^{10} = P( diag(\lambda_1^{10},\lambda_2^{10}, \lambda_3^{10} ))P^{-1}$$

In other words, to calculate $A^{10}$, you only need to raise the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix to the power of 10 and then multiply by $P$ and $P^{-1}$. Now that's a lot easier and quicker than multiplying A by itself 10 times. I hope this makes sense. There are several other applications too-you can read more to motivate yourself.

Comment: So if I just place the eigenvalues on the diagonal randomly, this would be associated with some order in $P$. But, the processes of diagonalizing must involve everything including calculating $P^{-1}AP$? I can't understand why...

Comment: @JoãoPedro, Yes that's correct. The reason you have to go through the whole process is because you are showing that the matrix A can indeed be written in terms of matrix D, i.e. $AP = PD$. It is a very clever bit of maths-will edit my post to explain further.